# What does "Can't call method "get" on an undefined value at " mean?

Tags: perl

I am executing a Perl file. I am getting this error. Can anybody please suggest the solution. I am getting this kind of error on many pages like:

> "Can't call method "goto" on an undefined value at " ..

Means error is same just by replacing  `get` method name.

Please help.

Comment: Please show some code.  It means you have an uninitialized variable that is being misused.  Does your script have `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the top?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 9):

It means the variable on which the method `get` is called is undefined instead of being an object that accepts the method.

Look at the line number given by the error message (in the file given by the message). If the error is in a module, and you don't see where the variable should have been initialized, then put `use diagnostics;` at the top of the script after your `use strict;` and `use warnings;` so you get a stack of the method/function calls at the point of error.

Comment: i am getting these much errors ;"Global symbol "$STRUCTURE" requires explicit package name at <filename>" .,..

Comment: then you need to declare `$STRUCTURE`, with `my $STRUCTURE` before you use it;